# Problems building Android Library with native code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I am trying to build an Android library project with native code. Per the "Known limitations" section under  http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental hybrid library projects are supported. But I don't seem to see the native so files being generated under the libs folder of the library aar file.

Here is how my project setup looks like

1. Followed steps in http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental for ndk support
2. Added a library modules that statically loads the native so file and exposes capabilities via some methods
3. Added another module that uses the native module. Set the module dependencies to include the library project.

When I run this app I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError, which I expected as I see no native so files being generated in the aar file.

This is how my library build.gradle file looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

model {
     android {
         compileSdkVersion = 23
         buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"
     }
     android.ndk {
         moduleName = "native"
         cppFlags = ['-std=c++11']
         stl = "gnustl_shared"
     }
}
```

This is how my app module's build.gradle looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':mylibrary')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem in gradle experimental 0.2.0 and 0.2.1. Had the same problem, upgraded to [0.3.0-alpha4](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle-experimental/0.3.0-alpha4/view) and it worked (just replace `0.2.0` with `0.3.0-alpha4` in your project's build.gradle). To upgrade you will need Gradle 2.6 (right click on a module/Open Module Settings/ select the *Project* submenu/ set *Gradle version* field to 2.6). Note that I am using Android Studio 1.4 RC3.

Comment: Worked with 0.3.0-alpha4 and gradle 2.6. I did not have to upgrade from AS 1.3.2

Comment: Are you able to debug the native code? I have a problem with that and I'm wondering if debugging in hybrid library is not yet supported or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: What error do you see? I get the following when I debug a hybrid library project "Error while launching on device debug server: com.android.tools.ndk.run.DebuggerContext$StartServerException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: LLDB server not found". BTW I am able to debug a hybrid application project with no problems

Comment: I get exactly the same error in AS 1.3.2. In 1.4 RC3 there is no error, the debugger seem attached but no breakpoints in the native code are hit.  I am able to debug a project with a hybrid application module, too, but I don't think I can use it as a library. Please let me know if you think of a workaround.